# Wordpress sort by meta_value not working with meta_query

Tags: wordpress

I have a template that pulls a custom post type for properties and sorts them by state.  The script works properly until you add in a meta_query for the agent.  It pulls the correct properties, but it doesn't sort them by state with the meta_query present.  Here's the query:

```
$qry = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'practices-tpsg' ),
        'meta_key'  => 'wpcf-practice-state',
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
        'order'     => 'asc',
        'showposts' => 18,
        'paged'     =>$paged
    );

if($_GET['agent'])
{
    $qry['meta_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-agent',
            'value' => $_GET['agent']
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-agent2',
            'value' => $_GET['agent']
        ),
    );
}
```

Does anyone know why it would stop sorting properly after the meta_query is added to the query?

Here's a link to the page:  http://www.totalpracticesolutionsgroup.com/practices-for-sale/  The sort order works properly in the default view, which allows the state name headers above the listings.  If you select an agent from the drop down in the top right, the correct properties are pulled, but they are no longer sorted by state.  You can also see the output of the query by adding &debug=1 to the end of the url.

Comment: Is `$_GET['agent']` a string, or an array?

Comment: @rnevius - it's a string

Comment: And it's not numeric? Really odd...

Comment: @rnevius - I was wrong, $_GET['agent'] is numeric.  But the query is supposed to be sorted by the name of the state... that shouldn't affect it, should it?

Comment: @KevinDaniel did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

replace `'orderby'   => 'meta_value'` with `'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num`

Comment: That's not it...  The orderby value is the state name; meta_value_num completely breaks it.

Comment: The way things are currently set up, you're ordering by your `$_GET['agent']`...which is numeric, according to your comment above. This answer should be correct.

Comment: So how would it need to be structured to order by the state?

Comment: you can pass multiple aruguments in orderby like so `'orderby' => ` `'meta_value meta_value_num'`

Comment: Every time I add meta_value_num to the orderby, the sort order doesn't work at all.  I'm trying to sort by the state name, which isn't numeric.

Comment: I've added a link to the original question along with a little bit more in the way of an explanation so that you can see what it's doing.